# What is an easy way to commit work half way through a transaction, but then continue to

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, go, transactions

### Background

I am using the `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx` golang package with a Postgres database.

I have the following wrapper function to run SQL code in a transaction:

```
func (s *postgresStore) runInTransaction(ctx context.Context, fn func(*sqlx.Tx) error) error {
    tx, err := s.db.Beginx()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            return
        }
        err = tx.Commit()
    }()
    err = fn(tx)
    return err
}
```

Given this, consider the following code:

```
func (s *store) SampleFunc(ctx context.Context) error {
    err := s.runInTransaction(ctx,func(tx *sqlx.Tx) error {

        // Point A: Do some database work

        if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // Point B: Do some more database work, which may return an error
    })
}
```

### Desired behavior

- If there is an error at Point A, then the transaction should have done zero work
- If there is an error at Point B, then the transaction should still have completed the work at Point A.

### Problem with current code

The code does not work as intended at the moment, because I am committing the transaction twice (once in `runInTransaction`, once in `SampleFunc`).

### A Possible Solution

Where I commit the transaction, I could instead run something like `tx.Exec("SAVEPOINT my_savepoint")`, then `defer tx.Exec("ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT my_savepoint")`

After the code at Point B, I could run: `tx.Exec("RELEASE SAVEPOINT my_savepoint")`

So, if the code at Point B runs without error, I will fail to `ROLLBACK` to my savepoint.

### Problems with Possible Solution

I'm not sure if using savepoints will mess with the database/sql package's behavior. Also, my solution seems a bit messy -- surely there is a cleaner way to do this!

Comment: how about splitting your function in two and running one after another in separate transactions? if the first one fails do not run the second.

Comment: See my comment to your answer.

Comment: See [https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7898](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7898). Sub(nested)-transaction is not yet supported, but you can use `SAVEPOINT` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @putu, is the solution I proposed the way to go?

Comment: Yes, use the proposed method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the problem alike: I had a lots of steps in one transaction. 
After starting transaction:

- `BEGIN`
- In loop:

  - `SAVEPOINT s1`
  - Some actions ....
  - If I get an error: `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT s1`
  - If OK go to next step
- Finally `COMMIT`

This approach gives me ability to perform all steps one-by-one. If some steps got failed I can throw away only them, keeping others. And finally commit all "good" work.

Answer (score 2):

## Multiple transactions

You can split your work in two transactions:

```
func (s *store) SampleFunc(ctx context.Context) error {
    err := s.runInTransaction(ctx,func(tx *sqlx.Tx) error {
        // Point A: Do some database work
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return s.runInTransaction(ctx,func(tx *sqlx.Tx) error {
        // Point B: Do some more database work, which may return an error
    })
}
```

Comment: The reason I'd like to avoid this is that I insert a new row in Point A, and do not want that row to be modified before Point B is complete. If I have two distinct transactions, then someone else could possibly mess around with the row from Point B. Is it possible to use nested transactions?

Comment: In this case your possible solution using safepoints should work (if your database supports safepoints).

Comment: Make that [`savepoint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html) (“v” not "f”).